# How to plot my graphs in different windows with "matplotlib.pyplot"?

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I have 4 arrays that `p1&p2` and `v1&v2` are similar and I like to plotting them on 2 different windows. I use the following code to plot all of them in 1 window, but like to separate them as I said above:

```
p1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,1]
p2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,1]
plt.plot(p1, color = 'red', label = 'p1')
plt.plot(v1, color = 'brown', label = 'v1')
plt.plot(p2, color = 'blue', label = 'p2')
plt.plot(v2, color = 'green', label = 'v2')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How should I change my code?

Comment: Use `pyplot.figure()` for every plot you want to display in a separate window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `plt.figure()` before each plot call to achieve this.

```
p1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,1]
p2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(p1, color = 'red', label = 'p1')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(v1, color = 'brown', label = 'v1')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(p2, color = 'blue', label = 'p2')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')

plt.figure(4)
plt.plot(v2, color = 'green', label = 'v2')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: He asked for only 2 windows not for 4

Comment: @Manojbiroj: your answer also creates only 1 window not two bro :)

Answer (score 1):

You should put the code for different plots between `plt.figure()` and `plt.show()` as follows:

```
p1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,1]
p2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,1]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(p1, color = 'red', label = 'p1')
# you can add other instrunctions here, such as title, xlabel, etc
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(v1, color = 'brown', label = 'v1')
# you can add other instrunctions here, such as title, xlabel, etc
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(p2, color = 'blue', label = 'p2')
# you can add other instrunctions here, such as title, xlabel, etc
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

use plt.subplot() for splitting the graph into two windows.Try the below code it will work

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(p1, color = 'red', label = 'p1')
plt.plot(v1, color = 'blue', label = 'v1')
plt.title('real Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(p2, color = 'brown', label = 'p2')
plt.plot(v2, color = 'green', label = 'v2')
plt.title('Predicted Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```